# Xcode gets stuck on "compiling 2 of 2 source files"

Tags: xcode, compiler-construction, build, archive, freeze

Xcode gets stuck on "compiling 2 of 2 source files" when I try to build for archive! 
Sometimes it gets stuck on "compiling 22 of 22 source files".
The whole computer gets slow and freezes when this happens!

Comment: I'm had the same problem. The answer is here:<br>
[Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944175/xcode-4-5-1-get-stuck-when-archiving/12988404#12988404)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode 4.5.1 get stuck when archiving](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944175/xcode-4-5-1-get-stuck-when-archiving)