# Xcode 4.5.1 get stuck when archiving

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios5, ios6

I just upgraded my xcode to version 4.5.1. 
Everything worked fine before but now, when I Archive the project, **xcode get stuck/hanging** and never finishes the archiving.
In the status on top, the text says:

> Compiling 10 of 10 source files...

Nothing happens after that. It is just stuck.
I can still compile and build the code (without archiving) and everything runs just fine in the simulator.
I have reinstalled xcode. The issue still happens after that.
Any suggestion will be appriciated.

**More info:**
I've pinpointed the problem to a specific line of code:
`CGRect tmpFrame3 = seeDetailsButton.frame;`
I don't see any problem with this line...
Why would it work fine when building and running in the simulator but fail when archiving???

Comment: What about the Log pane; that will tell you what Xcode is doing when it gets stuck...

Comment: Do you get the spinning color wheel?

Comment: when the bug happens - the log pane is stuck and does not say anything about it. I do not get the spinning color wheel. it is just stuck. I've found out what the issue is and posted my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out what is going on here.
First, it is not related to the archive process itself but to the build in *Release* mode.
The reason that I had the problem during archive is because then it builds in release mode.
About the issue itself:
It seems that there is some sort of an **Apple compiler bug** in xcode 4.5.1.
I'm using the Apple LLVM compiler 4.1. During compilation it has different optimization levels.
In Debug - the optimization is set to 'None' and is off. In release it is set to 'Fastest, Smallest [-Os]'. When I turn off the optimization in release mode (set it to 'None') - the issue does not happen.

More info:
After digging in my code, and trying to figure out what would cause a compiler bug during optimization, I saw that I had the following:

```
__weak ProfileButton *tmp = myButton;
```

Where ProfileButton is just a regular button inherits from UIButton.
When I remove the `__weak` everything works just fine. Even when I set the compiler optimization to 'Fastest, Smallest [-Os]'.

Comment: Sadly that doesn't work for me, Xcode 5.1, LLVM 5.1 Code Generator

Answer (score 0):

Recently faced this same issue, with Xcode hanging on the final file during compile. In the same fashion as the problem above, setting the optimization level for release to None ([-O0] to match the debug mode) would allow archive to run successfully.

However, for our code the specific bug was tied to a block that was capturing self. Per [Apple's guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH8-SW16):

> "If you need to capture self in a block, such as when defining a
>   callback block, it’s important to consider the memory management
>   implications.
>
> Blocks maintain strong references to any captured objects, including
>   self, which means that it’s easy to end up with a strong reference
>   cycle..."

So be sure to check your code for this, if applicable, and follow Apple's best practice to capture a weak reference to self ([example in documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH8-SW16)).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I created a circlic subclass

It was like

```
@interface BaseTableViewController : PaymentTableViewController
```

and

```
@interface PaymentTabelViewController : BaseTableViewController
```

What i did was to reneme the last subclass, so it now looks like this:

```
@interface TopTableViewController : PaymentTableViewController
```

and

```
@interface PaymentTableViewController : BaseTableViewController
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue arose when one of source files contained a declaration of a very large array like this:

```
NSArray<NSArray<NSNumber *> *> *points =
    @[
        @[@38.576732f, @-90.230682f, @1495320246], // 1 item
        ...
        @[@37.478034f, @-89.524851f, @1495336147] // 3000 item
    ];
```

There were about 3k items. Splitting the source line into small ones doesn't helped.

Fixed it by placing items in a CSV file and parsed it at run-time.

Another approach could be splitting into smaller arrays and concatenating at the run-time.